# "snap to face" going nuts on me

Tags: snapping

so i'm following the Donut tutorial from Blender Guru (on youtube) and everything is fine except "snap to face" option behaves a bit weird. things look completely normal from my point of view but when i rotate my view everything is fruited to oblivion:[image: as you can see]
i'm trying to grab the icing and move it a bit higher up on the donut. i have snap on and i set it to face + project indivi...
[image: looks fine]
i think i did it properly.
but when i change my view...
[image: Bam!]
disaster...

i just moved a vertex a tiny bit! like literally a just a dozen pixels.. what am i doing wrong? how can i fix this?

Comment: You have proportional editing turned on (blue and white target hilighted below 'Compositing' entry on toolbar). I'm guessing that the circle of influence is turned up much too high if it's supposed to be on. Try reducing the size with the scrollbar while dragging the vertex.

Comment: That should read 'scroll wheel' not 'scrollbar' of course! :^(